# Vue.js3 event @keydown.esc on text input is not triggered

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs3, onblur, vue-events

I have a text field with various events. All events are working, but not `@keydown.esc`.

I would like to differ between `@blur` and `@keydown.esc`. Escape should always do something and `@blur` only sometimes.

Found this code [codepen.io/whitelynx/pen/wGvmdW](https://codepen.io/whitelynx/pen/wGvmdW)
that shows the key code for every key, but not for escape.

Is there anything special with `@keydown.esc` in vue js 3? That was not an issue in version 2.

My element

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchQuery" @keyup="searchItems" @paste="searchItems" @keydown.down="arrowDown" @keydown.up="arrowUp" @keydown.enter="selectIndex"
@keyup.,="selectIndex" @keydown.esc="closeSearch" @blur="maybeCloseSearch"
@focus="initSearch" placeholder="Search …" autocomplete="off" \>
```

I tried to remove all the other events and only @keydown.esc, but that makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Solution": I found out that my browser extension Vimium i causes this problem

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the error:

wrong end of the input tag

```
    \>
```

Define all methods

**It works!**

### Playground

```js
const App = {
  data() { return { searchQuery: null } },
  methods: {
    initSearch: () => console.log('initSearch'),
    closeSearch: () => console.log('closeSearch'),
    maybeCloseSearch: () => console.log('maybeCloseSearch'),
  }
}
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchQuery" @keydown.esc="closeSearch" @blur="maybeCloseSearch" @focus="initSearch" placeholder="Search …" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Two things:

This handles the comma event:
 @keyup.,="selectIndex"

I testet your code snippet. keydown.esc triggers maybeCloseSearch not closeSearch.

The same behaviour is on codepen.io/whitelynx/pen/wGvmdW.

Comment: I guess, this is some problem with your browser. It does work as intended with my setup (Win10+Chrome|Edge.). ESC fires `closeSearch`. Do you use Safari?

Comment: I am using Chrome on Mac

Comment: Then it could be Mac problem. Sorry, have no experience with Macs

Comment: But its working i Safari

Comment: @Tolbxela, according to [this](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/keycode-modifiers.html#migration-strategy), `@keyup.,` is valid. The list of invalid key modifiers is `"`, `'`, `/`, `=`, `>`, and `.`.

Comment: You are right @tao. Thanks for notice! I have updated my answer.